# Wakanda How to access and display the data in mobile side?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, wakanda

In the getting started on Wakanda it explain how I can bind my data in my web app via AngularJs.

```
http://wakanda.github.io/get-started/bind-data-in-webapp.html
```

The mobile app work with Ionic 2, and I want to know, how I can bind the data like the web app ?

My goal is to have the same result as the getting started but on the mobile side. Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result in Ionic 2 project by using the *wakanda.service*. all you have to do is :

1. In home.ts for example

   `import { Wakanda  } from '../../app/wakanda.service';`
2. Add Wakanda to providers array

   `@Component({
     selector: 'page-home',
     providers: [Wakanda],
     templateUrl: 'home.html'
   })`
3. Add Wakanda to the constructor

   `constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public wakanda: Wakanda) {}`
4. You can use the service like this :

   `getHeros() {
           this.wakanda.getCatalog().then(ds => {
               ds['Superhero'].query({orderBy:"ID desc",pageSize:3}).then(collection => {
                   this.favoriteSuperheroes = collection.entities;
               });
           });
       }`
5. Display heros in home.html :

   `<ion-content padding>
     <button ion-button  (click)= getHeros()>Display Heros</button>
     <ion-list>
       <ion-item *ngFor="let superhero  of favoriteSuperheroes">{{superhero.name}} </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
   </ion-content>`

For more informations about how to interact with Wakanda Server REST API please refer to this link [Wakanda JavaScript Client](https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-javascript-client/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just have a a little problem, I can't compile. I have this following message: "Property 'favoriteSuperhero' does not exist on type 'HomePage'." I don't know why, in my backend I have the right name (I see in Quickstart they write Supehero instead of Superhero).

Comment: I try something else with your link, for exemple when I try a "Find" I have this following message: "Property 'Company' does not exist on type 'Catalog'." the Autocompletion don't work so I don't have access to my database. Do you know why ?

Comment: For the first comment you need to declare favoriteSuperheroes = []; in the class HomePage, before the getHeros function